# Links from Other Applications Open Firefox without default user session

Tags: firefox, xubuntu

I'm using XUBUNTU.  It's been my favorite distro for many years.

Within the past year, a strange problem started.  When I open a link from another application, say Discord, it opens Firefox, but with a completely new user / session.  In that firefox window, I won't have any of my bookmarks, or open sessions with common applications.

I've been copying links and pasting them into the browser, but I'd like to get back to clicking on them and having them open firefox normally.

I'm not sure it's relevant, but my ~/.config/mimeapps.list file looks like this:

```
[Added Associations]
text/plain=sublime-text_subl.desktop;mousepad.desktop;libreoffice_writer.desktop;
image/png=gimp.desktop;firefox.desktop;ristretto.desktop;pinta.desktop;brave_brave.desktop;firefox_firefox.desktop;gimp_gimp.desktop;
application/pdf=google-chrome.desktop;pdfarranger.desktop;net.sourceforge.gscan2pdf.desktop;userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;brave_brave.desktop;gimp.desktop;atril.desktop;xournalpp_xournalpp.desktop;
video/mp4=org.xfce.Parole.desktop;vlc_vlc.desktop;audacity.desktop;
image/jpeg=gimp.desktop;firefox_firefox.desktop;google-chrome.desktop;ristretto.desktop;pinta.desktop;gimp_gimp.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=libreoffice-writer.desktop;libreoffice_writer.desktop;
application/msword=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
video/x-msvideo=vlc_vlc.desktop;org.xfce.Parole.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
text/csv=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/zip=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;xarchiver.desktop;p7zip-desktop_p7zip-desktop.desktop;exo-file-manager.desktop;engrampa.desktop;
image/gif=ristretto.desktop;firefox.desktop;
application/vnd.rar=engrampa.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation=libreoffice_impress.desktop;engrampa.desktop;
text/html=sublime-text_subl.desktop;org.xfce.mousepad.desktop;google-chrome.desktop;exo-web-browser.desktop;mousepad.desktop;firefox_firefox.desktop;userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
application/illustrator=inkscape.desktop;exo-file-manager.desktop;
text/css=sublime-text_subl.desktop;
image/x-eps=gimp.desktop;atril.desktop;
image/x-xcf=gimp.desktop;gimp_gimp.desktop;
image/vnd.adobe.photoshop=ristretto.desktop;
text/x-sh=mousepad.desktop;sublime-text_subl.desktop;
image/svg+xml=sublime-text_subl.desktop;ristretto.desktop;mousepad.desktop;gimp.desktop;inkscape.desktop;firefox_firefox.desktop;gimp_gimp.desktop;
application/rtf=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
model/x.stl-binary=exo-file-manager.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text=libreoffice-writer.desktop;libreoffice_writer.desktop;
image/vnd.microsoft.icon=gimp.desktop;ristretto.desktop;
text/markdown=sublime-text_subl.desktop;
application/javascript=mousepad.desktop;
image/svg+xml-compressed=inkscape.desktop;
application/epub+zip=atril.desktop;
application/octet-stream=cherrytree_cherrytree.desktop;exo-file-manager.desktop;
application/x-compressed-tar=org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
audio/mp4=audacity.desktop;
application/vnd.appimage=exo-file-manager.desktop;
application/json=mousepad.desktop;sublime-text_subl.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation=libreoffice_impress.desktop;
application/x-shellscript=mousepad.desktop;
application/gzip=pencil.desktop;org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop;
video/quicktime=vlc_vlc.desktop;org.xfce.Parole.desktop;
text/vnd.trolltech.linguist=sublime-text_subl.desktop;exo-web-browser.desktop;
application/xml=exo-web-browser.desktop;
text/x-scss=sublime-text_subl.desktop;mousepad.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
audio/mpeg=vlc_vlc.desktop;audacity.desktop;
image/webp=gimp.desktop;google-chrome.desktop;
application/vnd.openshot-qt-project=openshot-qt.desktop;
text/x-c++src=sublime-text_subl.desktop;
application/x-partial-download=exo-file-manager.desktop;
application/vnd.debian.binary-package=gnome-software-local-file.desktop;
image/bmp=ristretto.desktop;
image/tiff=ristretto.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/http=exo-web-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=exo-web-browser.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/chrome=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
application/x-extension-htm=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
application/x-extension-html=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
application/x-extension-shtml=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
application/xhtml+xml=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
application/x-extension-xhtml=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
application/x-extension-xht=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop;
audio/x-wav=vlc_vlc.desktop;
application/x-7z-compressed=cherrytree_cherrytree.desktop;
video/webm=vlc_vlc.desktop;
video/x-matroska=vlc_vlc.desktop;

[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/tg=telegramdesktop.desktop
x-scheme-handler/viber=viber.desktop
audio/mpeg=vlc_vlc.desktop
video/mp4=vlc_vlc.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
x-scheme-handler/chrome=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
text/html=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
application/x-extension-htm=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
application/x-extension-html=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
application/x-extension-shtml=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
application/xhtml+xml=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
application/x-extension-xhtml=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
application/x-extension-xht=userapp-Firefox-MQO3L0.desktop
```

Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1503529) helped.

It turned out I had multiple firefoxes installed. I needed to identify the correct one and make it the default.